# How to view requests made by all the user in activeadmin dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, request, activeadmin

I am a newbie in rails and using ActiveAdmin for my project. I have two separate models for Employee and Admin_user so I am not using any gem for assigning roles for these.

Employee has a separate page where he can request for leave and Admin can view all the leave requests in activeadmin dashboard. I have no idea on how to create a resource in activeadmin where admin will be able to view all the requests made by employees in his dashboard.

Can someone explain me how to make this work ?

Comment: @MarkMerritt I have already checked the documentation. It only says about the case when admin has different access levels. But I guess my case is different. I only have one admin and one employee model and no roles assigned to either of these as they are different models.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, in Employee page you want to users to request leave and the same data you want to see in the Admin page where the admin can approve and the same should be reflected to the Employee.

Comment: You need a request model and controller

Comment: @FaaduBaalak yes. Can you tell how to do that on activeadmin?

Comment: 1. Display all the Leave Request.
2. Allow a filter for Admin to filter for non_approved leave reqeusts. Read mode here- https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html

Comment: Do the employees log in through active admin? Or will you have a separate frontend for the page where they can request the leaves?